# Smooth Video Transitions for WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, video

I'm using VB.net 2010 and WPF 4. I need to have a smooth transition between two videos played on the mediaelement. I absolutely cannot use anything that requires me to use a winhost in the WPF window, as that will make my project impossible (since the video is full screen, and the controls are over the video)

Basically, I need for the video to play through, and then smoothly go to another video specified in code behind. I cannot splice the two videos together - they must be separate.

How do I have the videos transition smoothly, with no "blink"?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.darinhiggins.com/fading-two-video-windows-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing without testing here. You're probably going to need some CPU cores and a good video card.

If you have the memory, use two `MediaElement`s.

- Queue up both videos, one on each element.
- Set the opacity of the second one to completely transparent. They're `UIElements` so this should work...
- Use timers of some kind keyed from the start of playback on the first one so that you get an event a couple of seconds before playback ends.
- With that event delegate, start the video in the second `MediaElement`, animate the first one's opacity to zero while simultaneously animating the second one to fully opaque.
- If you need to do it again, set up the timer again and make sure your delegate animates things the other way.

Comment: I have good hardware, but I can't guarantee my end-users will. What would the minimum memory requirements be for this, do you think?

Comment: Depends on the size of the video files and how `MediaElement` treats them. Sorry I can't be more specific, but I think the best approach will be to do some stress testing on whatever design you end up choosing.

Comment: Thank you, MUCH appreciated. Videos files comprise 90% of the product. (It's a game.)

Comment: ok... but is there any opensource library to apply transitions to WPF MediaElement?